# Round date to the nearest 5 minutes moment as array

Tags: arrays, angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I need to Using a Date() utc , to round a time to the nearest five minutes then push it as array

example:

```
[
  "2019_10_9_00_05",
  "2019_10_9_00_10",
  "2019_10_9_00_15",
  "2019_10_9_00_20",
]
```

Code

```
const now = moment();

const time= [];

for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  now.add(5, 'minutes');
  time.push(now.utcOffset(-1).format('YYYY_M_DD_HH_mm'));
}

console.log(time);
```

output

```
[
  "2019_10_9_00_03",
  "2019_10_9_00_7",
  "2019_10_9_00_11",
  "2019_10_9_00_16",
]
```

any solution's please

Comment: What "round a time to the nearest five minutes" means? Is it 7:05 or 7:30 or 7:35 for 7:32 moment

Comment: Yes 7:05 , 7:10 , 7:15 . output i have 7:02 , 7:07 , 7:11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if minutes value is multiple of 5 first.

```js
    const now = moment();
    const factor = 5;
    const time = [];

    const minutes = now.minutes();    
    if (minutes !== 0 && minutes % factor) {  // Check if there is a remainder
      const remainder = minutes % factor;     // Get remainder

      now.add(factor - remainder, 'minutes'); // Update minutes value to nearest 5
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      time.push(now.utcOffset(-1).format('YYYY_M_DD_HH_mm'));
      now.add(5, 'minutes');
    }

    console.log(time);
```

Result:

```
now: 2019_10_11_09_19
["2019_10_10_21_20", "2019_10_10_21_25", "2019_10_10_21_30", "2019_10_10_21_35"]
```